# How to slow down a Video without changing audio pitch?

Tags: video

Now that v12.1 has the `Video` symbol, I'm trying to find a way to slow down (or speed up) videos, without changing the pitch of the audio tracks.

```
v = Video["ExampleData/Caminandes.mp4"];
VideoTrim[v, 10]
```

I also need to join them, and I'm not sure if this possible at all, or if the tracks have different rates just yet...

Comment: Have you looked at AudioPitchShift? Perhaps, using that, you can revert the audio channel to the normal pitch?

Comment: @SHuisman couldn't get it to work with the slowness and then I also don't know how to Join videos

Comment: I don't think there is such a function yet (e.g. a function VideoJoin) because that could only work if they have the same resolution, framerate, channels etc…
Of course you could get the frames using VideoFrameList, then join those lists, and then turn it into a video again…